# Building tensorflow with decode_jpeg for android

Tags: android, tensorflow, libjpeg

I have trained a tensorflow model on desktop. I used `tf.image.decode_jpeg` to decode the image and feed it to the model during training.

I want to deploy the model on android. Since`DecodeJpeg` is not available on pre-built android binaries, I tried using android's `bitmap` class to read in the input image. For the same image, the pixel values are different for the outputs of `DecodeJpeg` and android's `bitmap`. This causes the prediction of the model to be different for the same image.

I'd like to have the same behavior on the app, how can I build a binary with `DecodeJpeg`, with its dependencies like `libjpeg`, using bazel?